# Criteria Nested Functions

Tags: mysql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a json as follows in the column XXX:

```
{"LR":[0.1, 0.01], "PR":0.1}
```

I am able to use Criteria Functions to fetch data if it's not an array.
i.e.

```
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder
        .function("JSON_EXTRACT", String.class, root.get("XXX"),
         criteriaBuilder.literal("$.PR")), "0.01")))
```

I am able to write a sql query to get all rows which have a specific value in LR. Query as follows:

```
select * from <TABLE> where JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(XXX, '$.learning_rate'), "0.01")
```

Need help in writing corresponding criteria builder for the above SQL query.

Comment: OOP ORM's frameworks lets make simple SQL queries even more complex then they have to be.. Why not simply use a raw query (native SQL) iam pretty sure hibernate supports that?